# CoAP: Group similar resources under one

Tags: iot, coap, libcoap

I am using libcoap implementation of CoAP for one of my IOT application.

Query:
I want to group more than one resource under one topic. For example, I want to group 'current time' resource and 'date' resource under 'TIME' resource.

On GET request to '/TIME' resource, server should provide date and current time to client.
On GET request to '/TIME/current time' resource, server should provide current time to client.
On GET request to '/TIME/date' resource, server should provide today's date to client.

Also, I am using Firefox Copper plugin to test my iot server application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created both the /TIME/currenttime and /TIME/date resources, what's left is that you create a /TIME/ resource (the slash at the end does matter) and announce it in .well-known/core as `</TIME/>;if="core.b"`.

The GET handler for /TIME/ should return data in `application/senml+json` format, like `[{"n":"currenttime","sv":"10:40:25"},{"n":"date","sv":"2018-07-27"}]`.

All the details are described in [core-interfaces draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-core-interfaces-12#section-4.2), but that's the gist of it.

Comment: This usage of SenML was obsoleted by late clarifications to the specification. core-interfaces has not been updated to reflect that, and its future is unclear. You can still build such a service, but you should respond with the full URI in the "n" field.